# Correct version of NPM to use?

Tags: npm

When I go to https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm it shows 4.4.4 as the latest release.

When I go to the link from that page to https://github.com/npm/npm I see 4.5.0.

Does this mean 4.4.4 is a stable release and 4.5.0 is not stable?

I should use 4.4.4?

Comment: You can also browse the releases on [github](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases). There you currently will see [v4.5.0](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v4.5.0) marked as "Pre-release" and 4.4.4 as "Latest release".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the package distribution tags for `npm` by running this command:

```
npm view npm dist-tags
```

The output of which is:

```
{ latest: '4.4.4',
  next: '4.5.0',
  'latest-2': '2.15.11',
  'v3.x-latest': '3.10.10',
  '3.x-latest': '3.10.10',
  '3.x-next': '3.10.10',
  'v3.x-next': '3.10.10',
  'next-2': '2.15.12',
  'latest-1': '1.4.29',
  lts: '2.15.11',
  'latest-3': '3.10.10',
  'next-3': '3.10.10' }
```

So the latest version is indeed 4.4.4 and - as you have surmised - the *next* version is 4.5.0. You should probably install 4.4.4, but it's up to you.

If you decide to install 4.5.0, you can do so using `npm install -g npm@4.5.0` or `npm install -g npm@next`.

Comment: Sometimes `npm` upgrades via itself fails. I for once had trouble upgrading from v3 to v4. Then the alternative way to install the latest version is to use the [official npm install script](www.npmjs.com/install.sh) provided by `npmjs.com`.

Comment: @k0pernikus that problem with upgrading and breaking NPM is usually because of not also upgrading Nodejs at the same time and so running a new npm version over an engine that is old and not compatible.
 (yes: npm just suggests you to upgrade, without caring about warning on your nodejs version; hence leading to break the installation and not being able to restore it if not, as you said, reinstalling everything by the official website)